# Deleting 2nd character on each line with sed

Tags: sed, terminal

Write a `sed` command that deletes the second character in each line in a file.

```
sed -e 's/^.//' sample
```

The above command deletes the first character. But how do you specify the second character alone?

Answer (score 5):

```bsh
sed 's/.//2' sample
```

The trailing `2` is a "flag" for the `s` command in `sed` (just like the sometimes over-used `g` is), and it instructs `sed` to only apply the substitution to the 2nd match of the regular expression on each line. Since the regular expression is `.` (matches any single character), this would remove the second character from each input line.

You may use any positive integer after the final `/` delimiter of the `s` command to skip forward some matches on a line.

Answer (score 3):

If your `sed` supports backreferences:

```
sed -E 's/^(.)./\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

*In your specific case*

You can use the following rule

```
sed 's/.//2' sample
```

where `2` correspdonds to the 2nd character.

As an example for a dummy **input** file called `test.txt`

```
qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl
zxcvbnm
```

the **output** of the `sed 's/.//2' test.txt` command is

```
qertyuiop
adfghjkl
zcvbnm
```

---

*As a general rule*

You can can remove the `Nth` character of the pattern `.` (i.e. all characters) by using

```
sed 's/.//N' sample
```